# How to set an app property until next reinstall on Appcelerator Titanium Classic?

Tags: appcelerator, appcelerator-titanium

I want to create a counter as an application-wide property, but I don't want this counter to restart to zero every time I relaunch the app. I want it to persist until the next time the application is installed (that is, updated from the app store).

This is the code necessary to create the property:

```
Titanium.App.Properties.setInt('counter', 0);
```

What would be the best approach?

Comment: Typo? Should be `Titanium.App.Properties.setInt('counter', 0);`

Comment: Yup, that was a shameful typo.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Yes, but you also need to store the app version in another `Ti.App.Properties` so that you can check if the user updates the app.

Comment: The app version stored in tiapp.xml can be read with `Ti.App.version`

Comment: But to determine if the app is updated, you need to store the app version.